# becomeFirstResponder resets contentOffset

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIScrollView in which inside of that I have a UITextField, so what I did is that on the third text field, which is password, I scrolled down the offset of the UIScrollView:

```
#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ((textField == self.emailTextField_ || textField == self.passwordTextField_)){
        if (self.scrollView_.contentOffset.y != self.emailTextField_.frameY - self.emailTextField_.frameHeight/2){
            shouldAdjustOffset = YES;
        } else {
            shouldAdjustOffset = NO;
        }

        if (shouldAdjustOffset){
            [self.scrollView_ setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.emailTextField_.frameY - self.emailTextField_.frameHeight/2) animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.firstNameTexField_){
        [self.firstNameTexField_ resignFirstResponder];
        [self.lastNameTextField_ becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == self.lastNameTextField_){
        [self.lastNameTextField_ resignFirstResponder];
        [self.emailTextField_ becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == self.emailTextField_){
        [self.emailTextField_ resignFirstResponder];
        [self.passwordTextField_ becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == self.passwordTextField_){
        [self signupButtonPressed:nil];
        [self.passwordTextField_ resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Now the issue is that when I am on the next text field it resets the content offset back to 0, when I do:

```
 [self.emailTextField_ resignFirstResponder];
        [self.passwordTextField_ becomeFirstResponder];
```

. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

Just turn of scrollview scroll before showing keypad (becomeFirstResponder) and enable back the scroll after it,

```
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
[someControl becomeFirstResponder];
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[scrollview doTheScrollingHere];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Deepan you saved me a lot of time :) Only what I'll suggest is to override *UITextField* method ***becomeFirstResponder*** to check first if it is in *UIScrollView* and if is disable scroll for a moment

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    if ([self.superview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
        [(UIScrollView*)self.superview setScrollEnabled:NO];
    }

    BOOL accept = [super becomeFirstResponder];

    if ([self.superview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
        [(UIScrollView*)self.superview setScrollEnabled:YES];
    }

    return accept
}
```